# align Row text to the right corner

Tags: flutter

I am trying to align the "Book Now" text and the add to cart icon to the righthand side of the screen. I have tried adding text alignment property also tried with Expanded/Column. It doesn't get aligned to the right side of the screen. Any hints to fix this? Thanks

Sample code and screenshot below tried in - https://www.dartpad.dev/flutter

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        InkWell(
          child: Row(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: <Widget>[
              Icon(Icons.add_shopping_cart),
              Text('Book Now', textAlign: TextAlign.right),
            ],
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

[image: sample screenshot]

Comment: Your dartpad URL is incorrect.

Comment: do you want all the rown to be right aligned or just this one specifically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want it aligned on the right?

Use `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end` on your first row.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
      children: <Widget>[
        InkWell(
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Icon(Icons.add_shopping_cart),
              Text('Book Now', textAlign: TextAlign.right),
            ],
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Right-Aligned]

Answer (score 0):

**try this:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: MyWidget(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Align(
      alignment:  Alignment.centerRight,
      child: InkWell(
        child: Row(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
            Icon(Icons.add_shopping_cart),
            Text('Book Now', textAlign: TextAlign.right),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]